# Secure Guest Users' Org-Wide Defaults and Sharing Model update

Tags: apex, security

We are using force dot com site and on the first-page customer register them as a lead and there is no authentication anyone having that link and create a lead.
If salesforce it says created by guest user.

Will this update break our system:

"Secure Guest Users' Org-Wide Defaults and Sharing Model"

Also, it seems they are releasing this on sandbox and production on the same day is it possible to reproduce this on sandbox anyhow.

Comment: You can enable manually in sandbox or prod from setup - sharing . If guest user only creates record and does not need to view or update record after creating it should be fine.

Comment: They need to update and view as well.

Comment: view can be done by creating a [sharing rule](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_user_sharing_rule.htm).  update is not possible by guest user as far as i understand.  you can likely use a child 'shadow' object + process builder to handle the update, or apex code that runs without sharing.

Comment: You cannot uncheck the checkbox once you have saved btw... so this is a one way thing. Just found that out.

Comment: FYI - you can uncheck the GSU checkbox - BUT you have to remove all the sharing rules created the the guest site user first - which is unhelpful if you've created a bunch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several blog posts on this, but this one is probably the most relevant:
https://www.learncommunitycloud.com/s/news/guest-user-record-access-development-best-practices-20Y1U000000UkITUA0

The basic goal is to prevent unauthenticated users updating data since that is considered a security risk. Assuming you need the Guest Site User to be able to update a record it has just created, you have to follow the guidelines in the link, which is to run the DML code in a class without sharing. If the Lead needs to lookup other records e.g. Campaigns, you will need to share the records via a new type of sharing rule that becomes available once you select the secure Guest Access checkbox.

Re sandbox/production - the secure Guest Access checkbox is available in both environments. The recommended approach is to add all sharing rules and code update you need in the Sandbox, and then deploy the new rules to Production. Note - you can only deploy those rules once you have checked the secure Guest Access checkbox, but there will be a time lag between the rules being deployed and the sharing records being created, so plan for that as well.

If you have more questions, I would suggest posting them in the [Securing Community Cloud](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004mDI) group, since that is the main place for questions about the Guest Site User Changes